# Json Parsing in Swift when a key value is getting from the json itself

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

I have a json like below need to parse , I have looked into many solutions . Here I need to use the value of the start key to fetch next value .

```
"journey": {
                "start": "The6422Dcd89Dc070B243Da5743",
                "6422dcd89dc070b243da5743": {
                    "events": [
                        {
                            "event_id": "4af5dbc5-b8ae-492d-aa97-16bb9b0967c9",
                            "type": "sale",
                            "name": "SALE"
}
```

and I have created a struct

```
// MARK: - Journey
struct Journey: Codable {
    let start: String?
    let value: The6422Dcd89Dc070B243Da5743?
    let summary: [Summary]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case start
        case value = "6422dcd89dc070b243da5743"
        case summary
    }
}
```

how I can make it dynamic?

Comment: Implement `init(from decoder:)` and/or a custom key decoding strategy or decode dictionaries,

Comment: Parse `start` first, create a `CodingKey` from its value and then get the value for that coding key.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit hard to figure out because your JSON doesn't seem to actually match your struct, but assuming the question is actually that the key is in `start`, you would decode it with AnyCodingKey. (There are many ways to implement AnyCodingKey; this is just the simplest.)

```
struct AnyCodingKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String = ""
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    var intValue: Int?
    init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue }
}
```

With that, you will first decode `start`, and the decode that value out of the same container:

```
struct Journey: Decodable {
    let start: String
    let summary: Summary

    // This is the only static key
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case start
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // First, decode the static things
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.start = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .start)

        // Now decode the dynamic things using AnyCodingKey
        let dynamic = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self)
        self.summary = try dynamic.decode(Summary.self, 
                                          forKey: AnyCodingKey(stringValue: self.start))
    }
}
```

---

Here's a different version of the same thing, which doesn't require a static CodingKeys at all (sometimes that's nice, and sometimes that's just extra overhead). By creating a slightly more advanced version of AnyCodingKey, you can get a slightly nicer syntax. (This is the version of AnyCodingKey I really use.)

```
public struct AnyCodingKey: CodingKey, CustomStringConvertible, ExpressibleByStringLiteral,
                            ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, Hashable, Comparable {
    public var description: String { stringValue }
    public let stringValue: String
    public init(_ string: String) { self.stringValue = string }
    public init?(stringValue: String) { self.init(stringValue) }
    public var intValue: Int?
    public init(intValue: Int) {
        self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) { self.init(value) }
    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) { self.init(intValue: value) }
    public static func < (lhs: AnyCodingKey, rhs: AnyCodingKey) -> Bool {
        lhs.stringValue < rhs.stringValue
    }
}

struct Journey: Codable {
    let start: String
    let summary: Summary

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self)

        // First, decode the static things.
        // Note how you can use a string literal as a key with AnyCodingKey.
        self.start = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: "start")

        // Now decode the dynamic things
        // Note that you have to convert the String to AnyCodingKey.
        // Above, it is keyed on a String **literal**, which can automatically
        // convert to AnyCodingKey. That doesn't mean you can key with a String.
        self.summary = try container.decode(Summary.self, 
                                            forKey: AnyCodingKey(self.start))
    }
}
```